# NetLogo: "Dimensions are too large"

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to model animal movement in a large raster layer of 4113 rows and 6085 columns and a resolution of 220m. Memory does not seem to be an issue as of now; we have about 100MB RAM available and I've increased the RAM usage of NetLogo. However, when I try resizing the NetLogo world to the dimensions of the raster layer, I get this exception:

"Dimensions (width = 1129238, height=763785) are too large."

I am unable to understand how this width and height corresponds to the number of rows and columns of the raster layer. Does it have something to do with the patch size in NetLogo? Resizing patches/increasing resolution of the raster layer did not help.

So my questions are:
1. Are there any workarounds to this problem
2. How do raster dimensions correspond to dimensions in the exception message
3. What are the maximum dimensions that the NetLogo world can handle.

We could split this large layer into several smaller tiles, but it would be useful to understand the maximum dimensions that NetLogo can handle without crashing.

Thanks.

Comment: the answer to question 3 is here: https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/faq.html#howbig

Comment: as for questions 1 and 2, perhaps it would help if you showed the code you are using for "resizing the NetLogo world to the dimensions of the raster layer"

Comment: Thanks. This is the code that I use:    "let layer gis:load-dataset "xyz.asc"
resize-world 0 gis:width-of layer 0 gis:height-of layer". I currently split the raster into smaller tiles for the analysis, but I'd be grateful if there is some other workaround where I can use the full layer.